# App Check Debug Token Flutter Not Working

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I generated a debug token from AppCheck, but when I use this token it does not work:
[image]

---

Flutter Main:

```
  const debugToken = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
  bool kReleaseMode = bool.fromEnvironment("dart.vm.product");
  print("kReleaseMode: $kReleaseMode");
  if(kReleaseMode){
    await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate();
  }else{
    await FirebaseAppCheck.instance.activate(
      webRecaptchaSiteKey:  debugToken,
    );
  }
```

Still Fails:
[image]